# DAX Query to combine data from multiple rows

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I need to calculate the total working time of employees, based on the start time and end time on a specific day. In the table there are multiple rows with parts of the working time, but the gaps inbetween should also be taken.
So in the table below Pers.1 works on 3-7 from 08:07 to 08:34

| PersNr | Date | RideNr | StartTime | StopTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3-7-2023 | 1 | 08:07 | 08:21 |
| 1 | 3-7-2023 | 2 | 08:27 | 08:34 |
| 2 | 4-7-2023 | 2 | 10:03 | 10:03 |
| 2 | 5-7-2023 | 1 | 09:01 | 09:03 |
| 2 | 5-7-2023 | 2 | 09:04 | 09:04 |
| 2 | 5-7-2023 | 3 | 09:10 | 09:14 |
| 2 | 5-7-2023 | 4 | 09:25 | 09:27 |

I've tried this with a PivotTable, but somehow Excel is too smart and takes the underlying data and ends up with 21 working minutes (14 from ride 1 & 7 from ride 2). I need the outcome to be 27 minutes.

I've added the data to a pivot table, taking the min from StartTime and max from StopTime.
Than I've simply tried to deduct these 2 times. This doesn't work.

I would like to include this formula within the pivot table, as I need to refresh this data quite frequently and I've created this proces to be facilitated via a PowerPivot model.

Comment: Hi, can you try to create a table with this tool https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables and paste the table here in the question? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small powerquery should work for you. This would not account for a person who started working on Day X and ended at Day X+1 since your requirement was minutes per day.  This is the difference between first start time and last end time on a specific day, not the sum of minutes worked across different intervals.

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PersNr", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"RideNr", Int64.Type}, {"StartTime", type time}, {"StopTime", type time}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"PersNr", "Date"}, {{"Minutes", each Duration.Minutes(List.Max([StopTime])-List.Min ([StartTime]))}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]